# How can I prove that a systole of a close oriented hyperbolic surface S is a simple closed curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I looked into all the literature regarding systoles (ex. Katz) and everywhere I only see the statement, but without a proof. Also, if possible can anyone recommend me some articles or books on this topic? Thank you.

Comment: What definition of systole are you using? Without knowing that, it's very hard to answer your question. For example, if I simply look up [this definition on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systolic_geometry#The_notion_of_systole) I will discover that the systole is a certain real number, not a simple closed curve, so that's not what you're using.

Comment: I got the beginning like this: Let S be a closed oriented hyperbolic surface. I showed in the first part that a closed geodesic g on S is the shortest curve of all curves in S freely homotopic to g. Then, the systoles refer to the definition given in https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1062621219, but everywhere I looked they only stated this fact without actually proving it. That is why I am interested in proving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment and the link provided there, I take your question to be the following:

> Why is the shortest closed geodesic a simple closed geodesic?

Suppose that $\gamma : S^1 \to S$ is a closed geodesic.

I'll prove that if $\gamma$ is not simple then there is a shorter closed geodesic.

Since $\gamma$ is not simple, there exists a proper subarc $[x,y]$ of $S^1$ with $x \ne y$ such that $\gamma(x)=\gamma(y)$. The restriction $\gamma \mid [x,y]$ is therefore a closed curve. Clearly 
$$\text{Length}(\gamma \mid [x,y]) < \text{Length}(\gamma)
$$
Also, $\gamma \mid [x,y]$ is not homotopically trivial, because if it were then $\gamma$ would be freely homotopic to the shorter curve $\gamma \mid S^1 - (x,y)$, contradicting that $\gamma$ is the shortest curve in its free homotopy class.

It follows that $\gamma \mid [x,y]$ is homotopic to a closed geodesic $\delta$. Also, $\delta$ is the shortest curve in its homotopy class, and therefore 
$$\text{Length}(\delta) \le \text{Length}(\gamma \mid [x,y])
$$
Putting this together, we have found a closed geodesic $\delta$ which is shorter than $\gamma$, using only that $\gamma$ is not simple.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It really helped me.